# Prevent users from creating work items more than 5 in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-boards

I want to prevent  users from organization to create more than 5 work items in boards in each project. Also want to set a rule as more than 5 tickets if any users wants to create according to business need, we should enable the count.
Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps does not support such restrictions. In this case, you have to create your custom application via Rest Api, that rejects or deletes restricted work items:

1. Search work item: [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), use [System.CreatedBy] field in your query
2. Get work item details (if you need to check some additional fields): [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)
3. Update state ([Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)) or remove ([Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)) restricted work items.

Comment: Thank you. We are using SAAS model service.